# How to make ng2-bootstrap carousel slide?

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

I am using [Angular2 bootstrap carousel component](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/tree/development/components/carousel) in my application but the transition and animation effect when sliding from one item to the next is not working.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Yes I can confirm that it indeed isn't sliding on edge and chrome borwsers.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code works for me. It slides fine.

```
<carousel [interval]="myInterval" [noWrap]="noWrapSlides">
        <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides;let index=index" [active]="slidez.active">
           <img [src]="slidez.image">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>
                <p>{{slidez.text}}</p>
            </div>
        </slide>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-left left carousel-control"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right right carousel-control"></i>
    </carousel>
```